# Home directory for system users

Tags: users, useradd

What is the best practice when setting the home directory of system users that don't have a specific working directory.

I often have to create users to run specific binaries or scripts. Supposing that my binary is in /usr/bin and that my user will only be used by my init script to run this binary, can I simply run:

```
useradd --no-create-home
```

Or is it safer to specify a directory in /var, /tmp or else?

Comment: It seems unusual.  Why would you need to do that?  Can't you have a standing 'anon' user, or something like that?

Comment: @rayandrews It would be the same problem than with the user nobody. If multiple applications run under the same user, being nobody or something else, one compromised application can access the data of the others.

Comment: If there's a need for the scripts to keep data or customizations (paths, etc), I would create something like /var/users/<user>. If the user has no need to write/read anything then something read-only to the user like '/' - obviously don't specify home creation - as it's the default home for nobody and other system users. I would avoid world writable like /tmp for maintenance and security reasons (think someone writing user's .bashrc file?).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create something like `/var/empty` and use it for your all system users, or just specify something like `/dev/null` as their home directory. I use the latter for system users that just run one binary (often service). If program wants to store something, I specify `/srv/app` where `app` is program name and make the directory for it.

If programs like `useradd` require you to specify home directory, specify `/var/empty` and create that directory as root:root 0755. Otherwise, just specify something invalid but sure existing, being it a file or directory. It also advised to specify a `/bin/false` as a login shell, although it's easy to override.

Or just specify `/`. It's no matter where their PWD will point to, if you want them not to write stuff, being in `/` is normal as being in `/var/empty` for example.